# How to connect bitcoind mainnet node on AWS EC2 by using rpcjson?

Tags: bitcoind, client, ruby

I'd like to access bitocind mainnet node on AWS EC2 from ruby. I've written as follows using [rpcjson](https://github.com/jjeffus/rpcjson), however it cannot connect, then returned the error

```
client = RPC::JSON::Client.new 'http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@publicIP:8332', 1.1
```

**Operation timed out - connect(2) for publicIP port 8332**

publicIP is the Public IP shown on EC2 instance page.

On the other hand, when I wrote as follows in order to connect localhost testnet node, it has no problem.

```
client = RPC::JSON::Client.new 'http://rpcuser:rpcpassword@127.0.0.1:8332', 1.1
```

Could you tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you'll have to open that port on your EC2 instance.

Comment: I changed the Security Group HTTO 80. However, it returned error. How should I do?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004159/opening-port-80-ec2-amazon-web-services/10454688#10454688