# How to open the port 8332 on EC2 instance?

Tags: bitcoind, port

I'd like to access the EC2 instance that installed bitcoin mainnet node.
I've found out that I need to open the port 8332 of instance from the [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/41800/how-to-connect-bitcoind-mainnet-node-on-aws-ec2-by-using-rpcjson), but I have not idea how to do it.

I tried to add port 8332 on the security group, however I cannot select 8332 port, only can select 80.

[image]

Could you tell me how to open the port and access bitcoin node?

**Update**

I've set port as the attached picture.
However, it returned the following error.

**Connection refused - connect(2) for 'publicIP address' port 8332**

It means that I still cannot connect the instance? or I've already connect the instance, but returned error by another reason?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Type dropdown menu, change HTTP to All TCP; enter 8332 as the port number; enter the IP of the computer that will be sending RPC requests under 'Source.'

Comment: Dear Nick
I've tried add port 8332. Please check the update of question.